# NSPOSIXDomainError When Opening Encrypted Email Message from O365

Tags: safari

I'm currently dealing with an issue that has just recently started plaguing me. I receive emails form an external domain that is encrypted from O365. When the message is encrypted an attachment is provided in the form of a message.html. However when ever I click on the attachment I'm immediately prompted with a Safari error that states:

Operation Not Permitted: NSPOSIXDomainError:1

Comment: Did it work in the past, or did you just never double-click before?

Comment: Also, what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Google finds https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2296455 and https://appuals.com/error-nsposixerrordomain-on-mac-os-x/